How can I separate uncooked lentils and rice?
When putting various dry grains into containers I accidently poured some rice into a jar with red lentils. I would like to separate the rice from the lentils.

I would probably use both for example in some soup but the trouble is that the rice would take say 20 to 30 minutes to cook through and the lentils would take only 5 to 10 minutes. It is mostly lentils with a little bit of rice, so overcooking lots of lentils to get the rice cooked seems unsatisfactory. Cooking it for only a few minutes will result in good lentils with undercooked rice in it.
The two grains are almost the same size so sieving them doesn't work. I also tried putting a few into a flat bowl and shaking it but they seem to have almost the same density so they don't separate that way.
Are they any other clever (food save) ways to separate the lentils from the rice?

Not sure what good tags would fit here, feel free to edit.

Well first you spend many hours building an automated sorting machine like they use for tomatoes …. oh wait you wanted to save time?

With my rice and my lentils, a colander would separate them with enough shaking (the rice has to go through the holes lengthways). But do your lentils really cook in 10 minutes? Red lentils are fastest and area normally at least 20 to be still firm.

I wonder about cooking together in a fairly acid sauce, to slow down the lentils, or seeing if a salty enough brine would allow exactly one to float (rinse promptly and dry thoroughly)

Actually, overcooking the lentils until creamy sounds not that bad to me. But @ChrisH also has a point with the acidity.

Both white rice and red lentils take around 5 minutes in my pressure cooker so... you could buy a pressure cooker and make your soup in that maybe.

@Stephie When Red lentils are cooked until they dissolve, they're great at providing body and a depth of flavour to stews. I especially like to put a handful in a beef stew. Speaking of cooking the lentils until they're creamy... my personal advice would be to just make a Tarka Dal. It's a simple, mildly spiced, Indian stew (sort of) that's really easy to make, and it's great comfort food. It can be healthy too, depending on how much ghee/oil, and salt you use. Look for an authentic Indian recipe though.

@HollisHurlbut it seems many users suggest finding uses for the mix, but the question asks about separating the two components.

@Stephie Which is the reason why I added my opinion as a comment rather than as an answer.

A bit of a frame challenge: save yourself the effort of separating the lentils and the rice, cook both together instead.
Your mix shows hulled red lentils, those tend to disintegrate rather quickly. But that's actually intentional and one of the reasons they are sold this way in the first place. They make great fillers / bulk up stews and sauces and in dhal they are even the main ingredient in a mushy state.
So look at your problem from another angle and think what dishes or preparations would fit your taste and could benefit from the lentils while a few grains of rice don't matter.

If this is not an option for you and the methods of separation suggested in the other answers are not satisfactory, put on some music or a podcast and start sorting by hand. Or find a willing kitchen helper (children?) you can delegate to. Luckily there isn't that much grain mix in your jar.

As well as dhal where they're cooked until they fall apart,  I use that speed as a vegetarian alternative to minc when , combined with slower-cooking varieties to get both a sauce with body and some texture

I cooked them together in a soup. I noticed that the rice cooked through a little faster than I expected, maybe 15 min. I guess a few loose rice grains in a simmering/ boiling pot cook faster than pure rice in a rice cooker. The lentils did mostly disintegrate and with a batch of pure lentils I would put them in the soup a little later for less disintegration but it still worked out fine cooked together.

I don't know if this would work, but you could try winnowing your mixture: gently toss it through the path of a fan so that the denser rice falls down while the lighter lentils (with a shape that catches the air better) are blown sideways.
You could also try the Brazil nut effect, where gently shaking/vibrating the container sorts the contents by size, but I don't know if the difference is great enough here for it to work. If it does you could then just spoon out the top layer to separate them.
